# ¿Cómo puedo lograr buscar un número adentro del array?

Tags: java

¡Hola!, el problema es el siguiente:

---

**Ejercicio propuesto por mi profesor**

Necesito crear un programa donde se tenga un menú con los siguientes puntos:

1.- Alta de Numero

2.- Búsqueda de numero

3.- Imprimir los números

4.- Salir

NOTA: Al inicio del programa se debe pedir la longitud del arreglo el cual contendrá puros enteros. 
El Sistema tendra 2 clases, una donde estara el main y la otra donde estara el arreglo de enteros.

---

**El problema de mi código**

No logro que al buscar un numero me diga la posición exacta dentro del array, tampoco logro que al entrar a la sección de imprimir numeros esta los imprima todos.

---

### MI CODIGO

**1.- Clase Main**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestNumero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean salir = true;
        int opc, n, j = 0, l = 0, numeros = 0, dato;
        Numero num1;
        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de arreglos, por favor: ");
        n = leer.nextInt();
        num1 = new Numero(n);
        do {
            System.out.println("1.- Ingresar numeros");
            System.out.println("2.- Busqueda de numero");
            System.out.println("3.- Imprimir numeros");
            System.out.println("4.- salir");
            opc = leer.nextInt();
            switch (opc) {
                case 1:
                    if (j < n) {
                        j += 1;
                        System.out.println("Ingrese los numeros:");
                        numeros = leer.nextInt();
                        num1.setNumero(l, numeros);
                        System.out.println("Ingresando numeros.......");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No puedes registrar más numeros");
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero que sea buscar");
                    dato = leer.nextInt();
                    num1.buscarNum(dato);
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        num1.buscarNum(i);
                        if (num1.getNum(i) == dato) {
                            System.out.println("El numero " + dato + " esta en la ubicación " + i);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("No existe un numero en la ubicacion " + i);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Los numeros son: " + num1.getNum(i));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } while (opc < 4);
    }
}
```

---

**2.- Clase donde esta el arreglo de numeros**

```
public class Numero {

    private int numero[];


    Numero(int i) {
        numero = new int[i];
    }

    void setNumero(int i, int numeros) {
        numero[i] = numeros;
    }

    public boolean buscarNum(int dato) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numero.length; i++) {
            if (dato == numero[i]) {
                i = numero.length;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getNum(int i) {
        return numero[i];
    }
}
```

---

**Salida del programa**

```
Ingrese el numero de arreglos, por favor: 
2
1.- Ingresar numeros
2.- Busqueda de numero
3.- Imprimir numeros
4.- salir
1
Ingrese los numeros:
5
Ingresando numeros.......
1.- Ingresar numeros
2.- Busqueda de numero
3.- Imprimir numeros
4.- salir
1
Ingrese los numeros:
2
Ingresando numeros.......
1.- Ingresar numeros
2.- Busqueda de numero
3.- Imprimir numeros
4.- salir
2
Ingrese el numero que sea buscar
5
No existe un numero en la ubicacion 0
No existe un numero en la ubicacion 1
1.- Ingresar numeros
2.- Busqueda de numero
3.- Imprimir numeros
4.- salir
2
Ingrese el numero que sea buscar
2
El numero 2 esta en la ubicación 0
No existe un numero en la ubicacion 1
1.- Ingresar numeros
2.- Busqueda de numero
3.- Imprimir numeros
4.- salir
3
Los numeros son: 2
Los numeros son: 0
1.- Ingresar numeros
2.- Busqueda de numero
3.- Imprimir numeros
4.- salir
4
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 45 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > ¿Cómo puedo lograr buscar un número adentro del array?

Ya lo tienes y no hay ningún error.

> > No logro que al buscar un numero me diga la posición exacta dentro del array, tampoco logro que al entrar a la sección de imprimir numeros esta los imprima todos.

El problema no está en la forma como buscas el dato, sino, en la manera que ingresas el dato.

Así que el inconveniente está en esta instrucción:

```java
num1.setNumero(l, numeros);
```

La variable `l` representa la posición/índice del dato y nunca la incrementas, por lo tanto, cada vez que vayas a ingresar un dato, lo harás en la posición `0` (porque es el valor defecto que le diste).

**Solución:** Pon el operador **post-incremento** en la variable `l`.

```java
num1.setNumero(l++, numeros);
```

De esta manera le pasas el valor actual de la variable `l` al primer parámetro del método `setNumero` y posteriormente, incrementas la variable `l` en `1`.

Otra forma de hacerlo es:

```java
num1.setNumero(l, numeros);
l = l + 1;
```

**Observación:**

En este bloque de código:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
      num1.buscarNum(i);
      if (num1.getNum(i) == dato) 
          System.out.println("El numero " + dato + " esta en la ubicación " + i);
       else 
         System.out.println("No existe un numero en la ubicacion " + i);            
}
```

Estás llamando al método `buscarNum` en cada iteración, es decir, es innecesario el bucle for que has agregado, debido a que, este trabajo **ya lo hace el método `buscarNum`**.

El método `buscarNum` tiene una falla:

```java
public boolean buscarNum(int dato) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numero.length; i++) {
        if (dato == numero[i]) {
            i = numero.length;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Como agregaste la sentencia `return` afuera del `if`, el bucle for **siempre** se romperá, debido a que, esta instrucción (`return`) hace que el método termine su ejecución.

Te propongo el siguiente método: Hagamos que la rutina retorne el índice del dato encontrado, si no lo llega a buscar, devolverá `-1`. De este modo, podemos saber cual es la posición del dato y a la vez, sabremos si el dato se pudo encontrar o no.

```java
public int buscarNum(int dato) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numero.length; i++) 
    {
        if (dato == numero[i]) 
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

La forma de usarlo sería:

```java
case 2:
    int pos;
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero que sea buscar");
    dato = leer.nextInt();
    if((pos = num1.buscarNum(dato)) == -1)
    {
        System.out.println("El dato no existe en el arreglo!");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("El dato se encuentra en la posicion: "+pos);
    break;
```

Comment: Me he quedado con la boca abierta :0. ¡Muchas gracias por tratar de explicarme con peras y manzanas!. Soy nuevo en esto y esta respuesta ha sido de much ayuda :)